# WiX - How to link an ExePackage element into a Product

Tags: wix, fragment, exe, linkage, prerequisites

I am trying to include the VC++ Redistributable 2013 prerequisites installation in my MSI installer.

I have modified the `Fragment` written by [this guy](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Install-the-Visual-C-redistributables-file-vcredist-x86-exe-td7580169.html) to quietly download and install the vcredist_x86.exe package after performing a registry check (file - MyWixProject/vcredist.wixobj):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
    <?define vcredist_x86="http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/E/6/2E61CFA4-993B-4DD4-91DA-3737CD5CD6E3/vcredist_x86.exe"?>

    <Fragment>
        <util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\vc\Servicing\12.0\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\vc\Servicing\12.0\RuntimeMinimum" Value="Install" Variable="vcredist" />
        <PackageGroup Id="vcredist">
            <PackageGroupRef Id="InstallVCRedist"/>
            <ExePackage Id="vcredist_x86"
                        Cache="no"
                        Compressed="no"
                        PerMachine="yes"
                        Permanent="yes"
                        Vital="yes"
                        Name="Redist\vcredist_x86.exe"
                        SourceFile="Redist\vcredist_x86.exe"
                        DownloadUrl="$(var.vcredist_x86)"
                        InstallCommand="/q"
                        DetectCondition="vcredist AND (vcredist &gt;= 1)">
                <ExitCode Value ="3010" Behavior="forceReboot" />
            </ExePackage>
        </PackageGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

I am trying to reference this `Fragment` from my `Product` element (file MyWixProject/Product.wxs). I read that "[The contents of a Fragment element can be linked into a product by utilizing one of the many *Ref elements](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/fragment.html)". But how can a `ExePackage` or its `PackageGroupRef` be referenced from the main `Product` element? Or is there another way to compile the `.wixobj` and its `Fragment` from within the `.wxs` `Product`?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ExePackage works only in a Bundle, not a Product. MSI doesn't support multiple Products installing at the same time and the VC++ redistributable is just a Bundle with multiple Products in it.

Comment: So, I should create a Bundle that runs VC++ redistributable and then my Package?

Comment: Right. A bundle is needed if you have multiple packages.

Comment: Or you can add the c++ redist as a merge module:http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/install_vcredist.html